# Dealing With Long Time Task Such As SQL Query In Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, model, netty

I am learning Netty, but I cannot make clear about the Netty thread.

Which is the IO thread? I read some pages online, which say that you must not  block the IO thread. But, I do not know which the IO thread is.

For example:

```
 b = new ServerBootstrap(); 
 b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
  .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) 
  .childHandler(new SimpleChatServerInitializer())  // (4)
  .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)            // (5)
  .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);   // (6)
```

The `WorkGroup` or the `bossGroup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both bossGroup and workerGroup are thread pools that provide threads for I/O processing. bossGroup threads handle client connection request and will accept the connection and create a channel for each client. After that a thread from workerGroup will be assigned solely for this channel that may have both inbound and outbound packets going through. For Inbound packets, the worker thread will be invoked by an event and need to read the packets. For outbound packets, the worker thread needs to write them into the channel socket buffer for sending. That's why they are all I/O threads.

Then for preparing (getting messages/data from a persistence store like MySQL/MongoDB), if you put the business logic into the same worker thread, it will be blocking. In a worse situation, if the same worker thread is being used/shared by other channels. The business logic will block I/O of other channels that may have urgent (time-sensitive) packets to be processed. That causes problems. Hence, you should let the business logic be executed in a different thread (E.g. user-defined thread), or you can create a separate EventExecutorGroup and let the business logic handler be in that thread group.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: thanks     ，i  get  it.   i   will   learn  more  about  netty

Comment: if   i   try   to   put   the  mysql  query   into user_defined  thread   ,how     to   record   the   the  .channel   and    return   to   worker   thread   to    write   to  client

Comment: You just need to bring the channel reference to your own thread so that you can write the channel using channel.writeAndFlush(SOME-DATA-OBJECT).  But the best practice here is to not define your own thread. Please checkout [DefaultEventExecutorGroup](http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultEventExecutorGroup.html)

Comment: thanks   very  much   ，  it  is   the    first time  to    use   this  website   so   i   can  not   vote   up   for   you  .